# SSO with Azure AD Logout Screen

Tags: single-sign-on

We are using SSO with Azure AD as the id provider. It is working properly for the login process. But when logging out we go through the process and am going through the process and logged out - but am ultimately coming to a blank/white screen which is at this URL :

```
https://.....my.salesforce.com/services/auth/sp/saml2/logout?SAMLResponse=fVNdb6JAFP...
```

Currently these are our relevant SSO settings...

**Single Logout Enabled** : Yes

**Identity Provider Single Logout URL :** https://login.microsoftonline.com/3a707....

**Single Logout Request Binding :** HTTP Redirect

**Logout URL :** https://......my.salesforce.com/services/auth/sp/saml2/logout

What I would like is for the user to just be brought back to the same login screen they use to get in with SSO after being logged out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect users to the salesforce login page after SLO (Single Log Out) was initiated you need to fill out **Custom Logout URL** field in your SAML Single Sign-On Settings. Basically, this URL will be used to redirect users after SAML LogoutResponse with Success StatusCode will be received by Salesforce.